# Change a single byte in a file

Tags: windows, batch-file

Using batch files, is it possible to modify a single byte of a file?

I am looking to make the following change:

`Address 0x829: 1B -> 1A` in file `a\b\c.class`

as you can see it is an edit of a compiled java class file, if that helps, but I don't want to use Java.

Answer (score 1):

With pure batch it's extremly hard to handle binary data and if the data contains NULL then it will fail completly.

But you could use vbscript, that can handle it and is installed from WinXP to Win7

Comment: What is the NULL byte? 0x00? If so I definitely can't use batch xD Is there a simple vbscript to do it then?

Answer (score 1):

if you have `debug`<sup>1</sup>, that can be scripted

the `e` command edits memory

here is a tutorial: http://www.armory.com/~rstevew/Public/Tutor/Debug/debug-manual.html

<sup>1</sup> debug is only available on 32 bit systems. It's available in XP, but I left 32 bit behind after that...